# Qt : how can i emmbed icons/images in the GUI in Qt framework?

Tags: image, qt, embed

how can i embed icons or images my application is using , i don't what to hold image directory in my application root , is there any valid method for that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the [Qt Resource System](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/resources.html).

See the section *Compiled-In Resources*.

Comment: The link is broken